# How to restrict access to sub-links in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

Is there a way in Spring Data Rest to restrict access to the sub-links of an exposed entity?

For example a GET request for a specific user in my Data Rest application returns the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1"
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1"
        },
        "todoLists": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/todoLists"
        },
        "contacts": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/contacts"
        },
        "todos": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/todos"
        },
        "contactRequestsReceived": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/contactRequestsReceived"
        },
        "assignedTodos": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/assignedTodos"
        },
        "contactRequestsSent": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/contactRequestsSent"
        }
    }
}
```

I want users to be able to access other users and see the usernames, but want to restrict the access to the sub-links so that they are not able to see the todos of each other by following the "/users/1/todos" link for example.

I tried to use a projection to only show the username or the @JsonIgnore annotation to ignore the collections, but the links remain visible and accessible still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing more research I discovered the ExposureConfiguration class which is part of the newer Spring Data Rest releases. I had to upgrade from Spring Boot 1.5.8 to 2.1.1 to use it.

Now in my RestConfig I am doing this:

```
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

    ExposureConfiguration exposureConfiguration = config.getExposureConfiguration();

    exposureConfiguration.forDomainType(User.class)
        .withAssociationExposure((metdata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.GET));
}
```

Which prevents users from accessing any of the association links of my User entity.

There are also a lot of other options available to configure the entity exposure.
I wasn't able to find a lot of documentation of this feature but this:
[Customizing Default Exposure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.http-methods.default-exposure).